# Xamarin Android, cant display spinner DatePickerDialog

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin, datepicker, xamarin.android

In my app I am trying to display a spinner DatePickerDialog. The problem is that when I am running the app in my device the result is like this.

[image]

Otherwise when I am running the app on emulator(I tried to different) the result is this

[image]

The Csharp code is this

```
private void birthdateInput(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
                    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,Resource.Style.CustomDatePickerDialogTheme, OnDateSet, today.Year, today.Month, today.Day);
                    dialog.Show();
                }

    void OnDateSet(object sender, DatePickerDialog.DateSetEventArgs e)
    {
        birthdateBtn.Text = e.Date.ToLongDateString();
    }
```

and the xml code for the style is this

```
    <style name="CustomDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
</style>
```

My question is how can I mage to display like spinner on my device(and every other device) and why this happening? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Each API has had changes to the default themes. You can use the `deprecated` Holo Light and Dark themes to get the "old" style dialog with the spinners, otherwise you will be getting the newer `Modern` themed alert dialogs on later APIs that include the calendar by month view.

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, AlertDialog.ThemeHoloLight, OnDateSet, today.Year, today.Month, today.Day);
```

Note: These still work in the latest API-27 / Oreo

#### AlertDialog.ThemeHoloLight

[image]

#### AlertDialog.ThemeHoloDark

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately is not working. I am still getting the same result.

Comment: I am getting the same result

Comment: @KonstantinosEvangelidis Device or Emulator? What API level?

Comment: Device API is 24. Emulators are 23 and 25. I am getting the spinner result only in emulators.

Comment: Sounds like your device does not have that theme in its build (device manufactures do not have to include everything from ASOP and are known for customizing themes). You can look at the ASOP source and reconstruct the Halo AlertDialog theme.

Comment: Is there any solution for this?

Comment: You can look at the ASOP source and reconstruct the Halo AlertDialog theme in its entirety or implement your own spinner-based dialog.